# EF CORE Power Tools DbContextExtensions ambiguity

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I use the EF CORE Power Tool to generate database classes in two separate .Net class library projects.  A third WebAPI project references these libraries. The compilation succeeds when only one stored procedure is included in one of the libraries.  I get following error when a second stored procedure is included in the other library.  I think there are two identical DbContextExtensions that cause this problem.  How to solve this ambiguity? Thanks.

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'IPRehabModel.DbContextExtensions.SqlQueryAsync
> (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext, string, object[], System.Threading.CancellationToken)' and 'UserModel.DbContextExtensions.SqlQueryAsync
> (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext, string, object[], System.Threading.CancellationToken)' IPRehabWebAPI2 C:\Users\xxx\yyy\repos\theApp\IPRehabWebAPI2\Helpers\UserPatientCacheHelper.cs 58 Active

Here is the code for that contains the error

```
public async Task <List<MastUserDTO>> GetUserAccessLevels(string networkID) {
  string userName = CleanUserName(networkID); //use network ID without domain

  SqlParameter[] paramNetworkID = new SqlParameter[] {
    new SqlParameter() {
      ParameterName = "@UserName",
        SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,
        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
        Value = userName
    }
  };

  /*line58*/
  var userPermission = await
  _context.SqlQueryAsync <theStoredProcedureResult> (
    $ "execute [Apps].[theStoredProcName] @UserName", paramNetworkID);

  var distinctFacilities = userPermission
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Facility)).Distinct()
    .Select(x => HydrateDTO.HydrateUser(x)).ToList();

  return distinctFacilities;
}
```

Comment: Use different namespace in each or put all your dbContexts in one project or delete one of the files or do your data access in the library project and not in the app.

Comment: Each class library is in a different namespace respectively

Comment: Suggest you create an issue on Github and I will look into it.